# I am trying to show some hidden div in javascript, is this a good way to do so?

Tags: javascript

I am complete beginner in javascript, I don't know many commands. The thing is I want to show that three different div element in the same exact position while clicking three different button meaning each three button have their own separate dropdown. So I check if some other dropdown is showing when I click to open some other dropdown, then I close the previous opened dropdown so both thing don't overlap. Is this efficient way to do so ? 
HTML Snippet-

```
<header class="primary-header">
            <div class="big-wrapper">
                <div class="first-icon left col-1-3 ">
                    <img onclick="toggleDropdown(&quot;dropOne&quot;);" class="cursor-pointer dropbtn " src="assets/images/icon.32x32.user.white.png" alt="menu-nav">
                    <div id="dropOne" class="dropdown-content big-wrapper">
                        <a href="#">First Drop menu 1</a>
                        <a href="#">First Drop menu 2</a>
                        <a href="#">First Drop menu 3</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

               <div class= "second-icon left col-1-3">
                   <img onclick="toggleDropdown(&quot;dropTwo&quot;)" class="cursor-pointer dropbtn" src="assets/images/icon.32x32.hearts.white.png">
                    <div id="dropTwo" class="dropdown-content big-wrapper">
                        <a href="#">Second Drop menu 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Second Drop menu 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Second Dropmenu 3</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class=" third-icon left col-1-3">  
                    <img onclick="toggleDropdown(&quot;dropThree&quot;)" class="cursor-pointer dropbtn" src="assets/images/icon.32x32.menu.white.png">
                     <div id="dropThree" class="dropdown-content big-wrapper">
                        <a href="#">Third Drop menu 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Third Drop menu 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Third Drop menu 3</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="clr"></div>

            </div>

        </header>
```

Javascript-

```
var dropdown1 = document.getElementById("dropOne");
var dropdown2 = document.getElementById("dropTwo");
var dropdown3 = document.getElementById("dropThree");

function toggleDropdown(elementId) {
    if(elementId == "dropOne")
    {

        dropdown1.classList.toggle("show");
        if(dropdown2.classList.contains("show"))
        {
            dropdown2.classList.toggle("show");
        } 
        if(dropdown3.classList.contains("show"))
        {
            dropdown3.classList.toggle("show");
        }

    }  
    else if(elementId == "dropTwo")
    {
        dropdown2.classList.toggle("show");
        if(dropdown1.classList.contains("show"))
        {
            dropdown1.classList.toggle("show");
        } 
        if(dropdown3.classList.contains("show"))
        {
            dropdown3.classList.toggle("show");
        }

    }  
    else if(elementId == "dropThree")
    {
        dropdown3.classList.toggle("show");
        if(dropdown2.classList.contains("show"))
        {
            dropdown2.classList.toggle("show");
        } 
        if(dropdown1.classList.contains("show"))
        {
            dropdown1.classList.toggle("show");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can we get your HTML corresponding to your Javascript? It will help to make sure any solution works better. Without it we can only make assumptions we believe would work.

Comment: @Jhecht  I've added the HTML part. It's completely working, but I was wondering is it the efficient way of doing this.

Comment: efficient? I'd have to say no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your definition of efficient.  You won't be able to increase the performance significantly since it's probably executing in few milliseconds already.

However, you can cut many line of code by using `add` / `remove` instead `contain` / `toggle` (and if for some reason the `show` class is added to a second dropdown, your button will start displaying or hidding the wrong items).  You can also write a more generic function by looping into n array.  That would allow you to add buttons and dropdowns more easily (This code isn't tested but you'll get the point.):

```
var dropdownArray = [];

dropdownArray.push(document.getElementById("dropOne"));
dropdownArray.push(document.getElementById("dropTwo"));
dropdownArray.push(document.getElementById("dropThree"));

function toggleDropdown(elementId) {
    dropdownArray.forEach(function(dropdown){
        if(dropdown.id == elementId) {
            dropdown.classList.add("show");
        } else {
            dropdown.classList.remove("show");
        }
    });    
}
```

Comment: Yeeah thankss..  I know it won't increase performance significantly but I want to write good code. Thanks, Its much better now